# Ignore SSL errors in Zend_Http_Client

Tags: php, zend-framework, ssl, curl

In PHP curl there are two functions used to ignore all SSL errors (invalid cert, self signed, expired, so on):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

I am switching over to use Zend_Http_Client, but I can't seem to find a way to force it to ignore errors. (I don't have a way to test it just yet, I wanted to see if anybody has done this before)

So, does anybody know the equivalent function/functions to do this in Zend_Http_Client?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like this,

```
   $connection = new Zend_Http_Client();
   $streamOpts = array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => false,
                'allow_self_signed' => true
             )
   );

   $adapter = new Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket();
   $connection->setAdapter($adapter);
   $adapter->setStreamContext($streamOpts);
```

Comment: Ah, and is that only specific to the Socket adapter? I was hoping for something that would apply it to any adapter I used in Zend